# Bounded function, monotonic function and infimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is my attempt at the following question. The answer should be correct, but I have some doubts on step 5 where I claimed the sequence $f(x_0),\ldots, f(x_n)$ is bounded below for $x_n<x_{n-1}<\ldots<x_0$. I need this claim to use the theorem of infimum. So i would really appreciate if someone tells me whether this claim is justified.

---

(a) Show $x<\tan x$ for all $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

**Theorem**:
If $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x)>0,\ \forall x\in (a,b)$, the $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$

We will use the above theorem to prove that $\tan x-x$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

First, I will prove $\tan x$ is differentiable in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}$). 
\begin{align*}
\lim _{x\rightarrow a}\frac{\tan x -\tan a}{x-a}&=\lim _{x\rightarrow a}\frac{(1+\tan x\tan a)\tan (x- a) }{x-a}\\
&=\lim _{x\rightarrow a}\frac{\sin(x-a)}{\cos(x-a)}\frac{1+\tan x\tan a}{\cos (x-a)}\\
&=\lim _{x\rightarrow a}\frac{\sin(x-a)}{(x-a)}\frac{1+\tan x\tan a}{(x-a)}\\
&=1\cdot \frac{1+\tan^2 a}{1}=1+\tan^2 a
\end{align*}

1. So the limit is defined for all $a\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.
2. By the sum rule, $f=\tan x-x$ is differentiable in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, and $f'(x)=1+\tan^2 x -1=\tan^2 x$
3. Since $f'(x)\tan ^2x> 0$, $\forall x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we can conclude $f=\tan x-x$ is strictly increasing in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.
4. By definition, If $x_1,x_2\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, and $x_1<x_2$, then $\tan x_1-x_1 <\tan x_2-x_2$.
5. Our last job is to prove that the infimum of the set is zero. Since we have a bounded below decreasing sequence when going backward, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\tan x-x=0$ means the infimum is indeed zero.
6. Therefore $f(x)>0,\ \forall x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: You can use that $f(x)=\tan x-x$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$

Comment: @mfl Hi, can you elaborate more?

Comment: You have shown that $f'(x)>0$ on $(0,\pi/2).$ So, you only need to have $f(0)=0$ ot guarantee that $f(x)>0$ on $(0,\pi/2).$ But $f(0)=\tan 0-0=0.$